# Check if the in and out time falls between a specific time interval

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for a solution after a long trial and error workings. I have 2 columns in and out with date and time. I want to check if the in and out falls between the interval 10PM to 8AM. Further, for those which falls within this range, I want to check atleast minimum of 3 hours are falling within this interval. My data looks like below in col A and B.

I need the output in column C and D where column C gives me the in and out time falls between the interval and Col D give me if it falls more than 3 hours between 10PM to 8AM.

```
  In                        Out             Between 10-8    <=3hrs
09/24/2019 06:00:18   09/25/2019 01:00:22        Yes          Yes
09/09/2019 17:54:58   09/10/2019 03:32:03        Yes          Yes
09/03/2019 10:19:49   09/03/2019 23:22:40        Yes          No
10/01/2019 00:01:22   10/01/2019 11:49:39        Yes          Yes
09/24/2019 23:59:46   09/25/2019 09:10:38        Yes          Yes
09/09/2019 13:11:41   09/10/2019 01:36:47        Yes          Yes
09/09/2019 13:11:41   09/09/2019 21:36:47         No           No
```

Comment: Please add a mockup of what the output should look like.

Comment: @scott Craner - added the output view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I've tried this formula for col C

```
=IF(MIN(B2,INT(A2)+32/24)-MAX(A2,INT(A2)+22/24)>0,"Yes","No")
```

and this for col D

```
=IF(MIN(B2,INT(A2)+32/24)-MAX(A2,INT(A2)+22/24)>3/24,"Yes","No")
```

but I get 'no' for the fourth one because that starts early on the *same* day so that needs clarification.

[image]

**EDIT**

I think it's easier to take the two cases (00:00-08:00 same day and 22:00-08:00 next day) as two separate cases. You could combine them but it wouldn't be much shorter and would be less clear

Column C

```
=IF(OR(MIN(B2,INT(A2)+32/24)-MAX(A2,INT(A2)+22/24)>0,MIN(B2,INT(A2)+8/24)-A2>0),"yes","no")
```

Column D

```
=IF(OR(MIN(B2,INT(A2)+32/24)-MAX(A2,INT(A2)+22/24)>=3/24,MIN(B2,INT(A2)+8/24)-A2>=3/24),"yes","no")
```

[image]

You have the option if there is any possibility of a mega-shift from say 7:00-24:00

of adding the two hours 7:00-8:00 and 22:00-24:00 to get a total of three hours, instead of or-ing them.

Comment: thank you you response. However, I am still getting no for places where its needs to be yes. i.e., In: 09/07/2019 04:47:34 and Out:09/07/2019 13:58:46

Comment: Yes but those times are on the same day as well not '10PM to 8AM of next day' like it says in your question. I can add that to the formula later if you want to include 00:00 to 08:00 on the same day but probably you should edit the question to include 00:00 to 8:00 of same day.

Comment: Ya, I got it where it is getting mislead. Actually the reason I put the "Next day" is ideally the 8AM should not be before the IN time. However, the actual objective is to check if it is between 10PM to 8AM(Col C) and have minimum 3 hrs between 10PM to 8AM (Col D). I will change the question and please edit the formula including that as well

Comment: Hi, one more thing. For the 3 hours logic (Col D) I am getting yes for this is scenerio: In - 09/26/2019 17:11:13 Out - 09/27/2019 00:40:54; However, the time difference within the interval (10PM to 8AM) is only 2hrs 40 minutes only. Not sure if I am missing anything

Comment: Apologies - I have spotted a mistake, will edit answer.

Comment: Thanks! Worked as per the requirement,